# Error "Unhandled 'error' event" after running yo generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am trying to use the generator of generatos, the generator-generator, and I am facing an error.

```
henrique@liberato:~/Documents$ yo generator
? Your generator name (generator-documents) 

events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: this.env.adapter.prompt(...).then is not a function
    at Base.prompt (/home/henrique/.nvm/versions/node/v5.8.0/lib/node_modules/generator-generator/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:232:45)
    at askName (/home/henrique/.nvm/versions/node/v5.8.0/lib/node_modules/generator-generator/node_modules/inquirer-npm-name/lib/index.js:25:19)
    at module.exports.generators.Base.extend.prompting (/home/henrique/.nvm/versions/node/v5.8.0/lib/node_modules/generator-generator/app/index.js:21:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/henrique/.nvm/versions/node/v5.8.0/lib/node_modules/generator-generator/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:431:23)
    at /home/henrique/.nvm/versions/node/v5.8.0/lib/node_modules/generator-generator/node_modules/run-async/index.js:26:25
    at /home/henrique/.nvm/versions/node/v5.8.0/lib/node_modules/generator-generator/node_modules/run-async/index.js:25:19
    at /home/henrique/.nvm/versions/node/v5.8.0/lib/node_modules/generator-generator/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:432:9
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

Versions:

```
henrique@liberato:~/Documents$ node -v
v5.8.0
henrique@liberato:~/Documents$ npm -version
3.8.9
```

I already did npm cache clean and npm install -g yo/yeoman-generator/generator-generator. Already reinstaled node and npm.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to update `yo` to the latest version.

`npm -g update yo`

And if that doesn't work, then you want:

```
npm -g uninstall yo
npm -g install yo
```

Comment: neither worked for me.. my node environment is managed by nvm. Currently i am using node v6.2.0

Comment: @Chandru sounds to me like you have two npm installed. `which yo` and running `DEBUG=yeoman:* yo` will give you more information as to which paths are used.

Comment: yes. you are right. i had multiple npms and the path I have installed yo was different from my current npm path. So, I had to switch to the previous version of node and continue using generator commands.

Comment: You can do this: npm uninstall -g yo && npm uninstall -g generator-generator
npm install -g yo && npm install -g generator-generator

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. However, updating or re-installing yo didn't help me.

My node environment is managed by nvm, where I am currently using node v6.2.0. However, yo was installed long ago in my pc while I was using node v4.4.1. When I used v4.4.1, I didnt get the error.

So, conclusion is that the yo angular-fullstack commands are working in the same node version in which it was installed. As nvm is handy in switching between node version, its not a big deal for me. I use v4.4.1 only when i generate some angular components, and switch back to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. 
I'm also using nvm to manage my node versions.

In my case, some combination of `npm dedupe -g`, `npm update -g yo`, `npm uninstall -g yo`, and `npm install -g yo` did the trick.
I also re-reran `npm link` from my generator, since it is a local generator. I think if it's a generator you installed from npm, `npm uninstall -g <generator-name>` followed by `npm install -g  would serve the same purpose.

At some point during all this, the generator started working again, but I didn't notice exactly when, because I was running the generator as a part of my unit tests.

Eventually, I realized that the generator was working when I ran it from the command line, but not when I ran it from my test files.

At that point, updating [yeoman's test helpers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yeoman-test) (`npm update yeoman-test`) from `1.1.0` to `1.4.0` did the trick.